# Ansible: Task control

Tags: ansible

I am working with Ansible and familiarizing myself with task control in a playbook. I am struggling with the `fail` module and `fail_when` statement. Here is a lab I worked on, which seems to work, but I would like to see how this could be handled using the fail module or fail_when, IF it is needed.

Here is the task I struggled with:

- Install packages only if the current operating system is CentOS or RHEL version 8 or later. If that is not the case, the playbook should fail with the error message "Host `hostname` does not meet the minimal requirements", where hostname is replaced with the current host name.

Here are my issues:

1. Using `ansible_facts` in the `fail` module does not workout well it seems
2. I do not understand how I would use `fail_when` on this task

Here is my solution:

```
---
- name: Install packages
  hosts: all

  vars_files:
    vars/pack.yml

  tasks:

    - name: Install packages
      block:
        - name: Install packages and loop
          yum:
            name: "{{ item.package }}"
            state: "{{ item.state }}"
          loop: "{{ packages }}"
          when:
            ( ansible_facts['distribution'] == "CentOS" and ansible_facts['distribution_version'] == "8" )
            or
            ( ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat" and ansible_facts['distribution_version'] >= "8.1" )

        - name: Copy file to /tmp
          copy:
            content: "Welcome to my webserver"
            dest: /tmp/index.html
          notify: restart web
        
        - name: Check for firewalld
          yum:
            name: firewalld
            state: latest

        - name: verify firewalld is started
          service:
            name: firewalld
            state: started

        - name: open firewall ports for http and https
          firewalld:
            service: "{{ item.service }}"
            state: "{{ item.state }}"
            immediate: yes
            permanent: yes
          loop: "{{ firewall }}"

      rescue:
        - name: fail if any task fail
          fail:
            msg:   did not meet the requirements
  
  handlers:
    - name: restart web
      service:
        name: httpd
        state: restarted
```

I am using the RHCE exam book by Sander Van Vugt btw. This is lab 7-1. His Github is a bit lacking on the labs.

Here is the better optimized playbook:

```
---
- name: End of chapter lab 7 final
  hosts: all
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - vars/pack.yml

  tasks:

    - name: Install httpd and mod_ssl packages
      yum:
        name: "{{ item.package }}"
        state: "{{ item.state }}"
      loop: "{{ packages }}"
      when: 
        ( ansible_facts['distribution'] == "CentOS" and ansible_facts['distribution_version'] <= "8" )
        or
        ( ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat" and ansible_facts['distribution_version'] <= "8" )
    
    - name: Fail if the following is not met
      fail:
        msg: "Host {{ ansible_facts['hostname'] }} does not meet the minimal requirements"
      when:
        not (( ansible_facts['distribution'] == "CentOS" and ansible_facts['distribution_version'] <= "8" )
        or 
        ( ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat" and ansible_facts['distribution_version'] <= "8" ))

    - name: Copy tmp file
      copy:
        content: "Welcome to my webserver"
        dest: /tmp/index.html

    - name: Configure Firewalld for http and https rules
      firewalld:
        service: "{{ item.service }}"
        state: "{{ item.state }}"
        immediate: yes
        permanent: yes
      loop: "{{ firewall }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the fail module to stop the script with a custom error message. In your case you could use it like this:

```
- name: fail if wrong OS
  fail:
    msg: "Wrong OS: {{ansible_facts['distribution']}}"
  when: not (( ansible_facts['distribution'] == "CentOS" and ansible_facts['distribution_version'] == "8" )
        or
        ( ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat" and ansible_facts['distribution_version'] >= "8.1" ))
```

Whereas the failed_when can be used to define when some behaviour is to be considered a failure. No custom error message possible. Use it like this:

```
- name: check if file exists and fail if it does
  stat:
    path: /etc/hosts
  register: result
  failed_when: result.stat.exists
```

In your above script you used `when`. This one executes the task if the when expression is true, or it skips the task if the when expression is false. But it would not stop the script execution.

Comment: Thank you Hiran! Your example filled in a gap in my understanding. I did not know if I would use fail_when or fail module since it asked for a statement, so I used block/rescue, thinking the task would fail and drop to rescue fail message. I think also, it's the way the book is written that throws it off as well or possibly just me. Either way, thank you! I will update this post with my updated playbook.